# Regular expressions string within group

Tags: regex

First of all, I have looked over the various regex questions on SO, but
i could not figure out, how to solve my problem...

The goal is to build a RegEx that matches the conditon:

```
&lt;(some charackters that are not '&gt;')&gt;
```

Newlines should be ignored.

The only thing I could come up with is:

```
/&lt;[^&gt;\n]+&gt;/
```

This works well, until one of the chars &, g, t, ;, \n appear in my tested string.
I know, this is because of the negotiated set, that does not match that characters.
How can i define, everything, except the string

```
'&gt;'
```

will match?

Examples:

test<bla> matches,
but test<ing> does not match....

Comment: Why not just `&lt;[\S\s]*?&gt;` ?

Comment: i have no problem with downvoting, but please explain, why? Would help everyone to get better questions on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should use a negative lookahead assertion.

> <(some charackters that are not '>')>

```
&lt;(?:(?!&gt;).)*?&gt;
```

Note that this won't match new line character because we all know that dot won't match line breaks.

or

> <(some charackters that are not '>' or '<')>

```
&lt;(?:(?!&[lg]t;).)*?&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `.` does not span multiple lines, you can use

```
/&lt;[\S\s]*?&gt;/
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZ6uK5/1)